# How do I set environment properties in AWS codestar?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-code-deploy, aws-codestar

I created a spring project in AWS codestar.
I would like to pass environment properties to my application (e.g. DATA_SOURCE_URL). I can do it in elastic beanstalk in "Configuration" -> "Software" "modify" and adding the properties. But whenever a new deployment is triggered this configuration gets reseted.

I was wondering what is the way of setting environment properties when using AWS codestar.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: yes, by moving away for codestar :) it was just not worth the trouble for us.

Answer (score 1):

As it may help other people that search a solution
I finally get it to work by using the Saved Configuration function in Beanstalk, and calling it via the cloud formation template.yml : EBConfigurationTemplate (from the autogenerated template.yml by codestar)

---

```
  EBConfigurationTemplate:
    [...]
    SourceConfiguration:
      ApplicationName: !Ref 'EBApplication'
      TemplateName: "Saved Configuration Name"
```

After that my django application was able to read the os.environ['ENV_VAR_NAME']
as well as django.config that was able to connect to an RDS (Non-managed by beanstalk) to do the migration as a container_command